# Do frozen/disabled apps get triggered by broadcast receivers?

Tags: applications, disable-app

If an app is frozen/disabled, does it still get executed if triggered by a broadcast receiver?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Thank you for your answer.  Somehow I didn't see it when you wrote it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is truly disabled, it won't get executed even if it receives broadcasts intents.

I have a disabled application, which if it was enabled, is woken up by various intents such as;

`android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED
 android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
 android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`

Even though if it receives these intents it is still disabled, until I manually enable it.

However there are some applications which can filter intents of a partially disabled application.

For example Greenify, it can disable an application such that other broadcast intents are ignored, except for a few e.g GCM receiver or Telephony intents. So in this case it is woken up **only** by specific broadcast intents